# PHP hiding link name in table row

Tags: php, html-table

The following code displays usually 2 columns with links names `Engagement report` and `Personal report`.

There are instances where the second hyperlink field `$ccP` is empty, and I want the cell also to appear empty and not as `Personal report`

Please help in achieving that.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($login)){
  $Report=$row['ReportName'];
  $cc=$row['LinkEngagement'];
  $ccP=$row['LinkPersonal'];

   print "<tr class='alt'>
    <td align='Left'>$Report</td>
    <td align='Center'><a href='$cc' style='cursor:pointer'      >Engagement report &nbsp;</a></td>
    <td align='Center'><a href='$ccP' style='cursor:pointer'      >Personal report  &nbsp;</a></td>

    </tr>";
  }
  print "</table>";
```

Comment: php function `empty`.

Comment: **Why do you have to use all that bolded text?**

Answer (score 0):

Check if `$ccP` has something assigned to it, and only print if it does.

```
if($ccP){
    print "<td align='Center'><a href='$ccP' style='cursor:pointer'      >Personal report  &nbsp;</a></td>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($login)){
  $Report=$row['ReportName'];
  $cc=$row['LinkEngagement'];
  $ccP=$row['LinkPersonal'];
  $ccPLink=(empty($ccp)) ? "" : $ccp ;

  print "<tr class='alt'>
           <td align='Left'>$Report</td>
           <td align='Center'><a href='$cc' style='cursor:pointer'>Engagement report &nbsp;</a></td>
           <td align='Center'><a href='$ccP' style='cursor:pointer'>$ccpLink  &nbsp;</a></td>
         </tr>";
}
```